# Mail: Application isn't running

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I'm trying to execute simple AppleScript in Objective-C. The code is:

```
NSString *emailString = @"tell application \"Mail\" to activate";

NSAppleScript *emailScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: emailString];

NSDictionary *errorDict = NULL;

[emailScript executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
```

And got this annoying error:

> NSAppleScriptErrorMessage: Mail got an error: Application isn’t
>   running. NSAppleScriptErrorRange: NSRange: {27, 8}
>   NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage: Application isn’t running.
>   NSAppleScriptErrorNumber: -600 NSAppleScriptErrorAppName: Mail

It's no problem if I execute the script from Script Editor. I need some help — Thanks!

Comment: How are you running it otherwise, in Xcode? The code works just fine for me — even if Mail.app is closed.

Comment: I've got a big project, so it's impossible to copy-paste all code. I think, that the problem in osx settings. The same code works fine on OSX 10.8.5, but on 10.11.3 I have this error.

Comment: It might be a case then of allowing the app to permission in System Preferences > Security. Otherwise try adding another tell calling System Events before you activate Mail.

Answer (score 6):

Solved. My app using Sandbox. And if you want run AppleScript from it, you need edit entitlements file. In me case [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1802/_index.html) help.